# Earlier in the day meaning?

Tags: american-english, british-english, sentence, early-modern-english

Today ,while reading news paper I came across the sentence "she had gone shopping earlier in the day " ....what does it mean ......? My conjecture "yesterday ?

Comment: By the way: "what does it means" is not English. When you use _do/does/did_ to form a question or a negative, the main verb always goes in the plain form: "what does it mean".

Comment: Thanks for the correction My Grammar is Poor, can you please suggest me any source . where I can easily go through such rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*she had gone shopping earlier in the day " ....what does it means ......? My conjecture "yesterday ?*

Your conjecture is incorrect - "earlier in the day" means just that - if it's say 2:00 pm, then anytime between about 8:00 am and 1:00 pm *on the same day* would be considered "earlier in the day".

Comment: Thanks a bunch  explained terrifically It clears my doubts